# Python interactive library(pymidas) session warning

Tags: python, python-import, argument-passing

I'm using Python2.7 and a library called pymidas.

Within my python script I call the library with the following comand:

```
from pymidas import midas
midas.do('INDISK/FITS test.fits test.bdf')
```

All the code that I have further written does exactly what I want, but whenever the script imports midas I first get a welcome output of (py)midas, which is ok with me, but afterwards it asks me if I want a parallel or a new session.

Saddly this point needs human interaction in selecting parallel mode. By reading the documentation of midas I found, that midas has an option (-P) which causes exactly what I need, and forces midas to open without any questions asked and directly going to parallel mode.

Does anybody know how to achieve this in my python script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your script add :

```html
midas.do('.exit')
```

This ensures you dont get asked the next time you run the script.